# Sort Nested Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const list= [
{
        id: 1,
        amount: 20,
        dueDate: '2021-05-01',
        splits: [{ id: 1, amount: 15, dueDate: '2021-09-01' },{ id: 2, 
        amount: 5, dueDate: '2021-03-01' }],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        amount: 45,
        dueDate: '2021-07-01',
        splits: [{ id: 1, amount: 20, dueDate: '2021-11-01' },{ id: 2, 
        amount: 24, dueDate: '2021-09-01' },{ id: 3, amount: 1, dueDate: 
     '2021-10-01' }],
    },
    { id: 3, amount: 10, dueDate: '2021-08-01' },
    { id: 4, amount: 30, dueDate: '2021-06-01', splits: [{ id: 1, amount: 30, dueDate: '2021-01-01' }] },
    { id: 5, amount: 15, dueDate: '2021-04-01' },
];
```

I want to write function that sorts a list of invoices by due date (ascending) and returns a list of object containing the invoice id with below conditions:

1- For invoices with splits, sort by earliest split's due date,or invoice 1
(id: 1) the earliest would be split 2 (id: 2).

2- For invoices without splits, the earliest dueDate is the top-level due date.

Expected sorted invoices: [{"id": 4}, {"id": 1}, {"id": 5}, {"id": 3}, {"id": 2}]

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    function sortFun(a,b){
        if(a.splits){
            a = a.splits.sort(sortFun)[0]
        }
        if(b.splits){
            b = b.splits.sort(sortFun)[0]
        }
        return new Date(a.dueDate) - new Date(b.dueDate)
    }

    let result = list.sort(sortFun).map(x=>({id:x.id}));
    
    console.log(result)
```

```js
const list = [{
  id: 1,
  amount: 20,
  dueDate: '2021-05-01',
  splits: [{
    id: 1,
    amount: 15,
    dueDate: '2021-09-01'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    amount: 5,
    dueDate: '2021-03-01'
  }],
},
{
  id: 2,
  amount: 45,
  dueDate: '2021-07-01',
  splits: [{
    id: 1,
    amount: 20,
    dueDate: '2021-11-01'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    amount: 24,
    dueDate: '2021-09-01'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    amount: 1,
    dueDate: '2021-10-01'
  }],
},
{
  id: 3,
  amount: 10,
  dueDate: '2021-08-01'
},
{
  id: 4,
  amount: 30,
  dueDate: '2021-06-01',
  splits: [{
    id: 1,
    amount: 30,
    dueDate: '2021-01-01'
  }]
},
{
  id: 5,
  amount: 15,
  dueDate: '2021-04-01'
},
];
    
function sortFun(a,b){
    if(a.splits){
        a = a.splits.sort(sortFun)[0]
    }
    if(b.splits){
        b = b.splits.sort(sortFun)[0]
    }
    return new Date(a.dueDate) - new Date(b.dueDate)
}

let result = list.sort(sortFun).map(x=>({id:x.id}));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```js
list.sort((prev, next) => {
    let prevDueDate = prev.splits ? prev.splits.map(el => el.dueDate).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))[0] : prev.dueDate;
    let nextDueDate = next.splits ? next.splits.map(el => el.dueDate).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))[0] : next.dueDate;

    return prevDueDate.localeCompare(nextDueDate);
}).map(el => ({ id: el.id }));
```

See these references for more help:

[MDN - Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

[MDN - String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
const list= [
    {
        id: 1,
        amount: 20,
        dueDate: '2021-05-01',
        splits: [{ id: 1, amount: 15, dueDate: '2021-09-01' },{ id: 2, 
        amount: 5, dueDate: '2021-03-01' }],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        amount: 45,
        dueDate: '2021-07-01',
        splits: [{ id: 1, amount: 20, dueDate: '2021-11-01' },{ id: 2, 
        amount: 24, dueDate: '2021-09-01' },{ id: 3, amount: 1, dueDate: 
     '2021-10-01' }],
    },
    { id: 3, amount: 10, dueDate: '2021-08-01' },
    { id: 4, amount: 30, dueDate: '2021-06-01', splits: [{ id: 1, amount: 30, dueDate: '2021-01-01' }] },
    { id: 5, amount: 15, dueDate: '2021-04-01' },
];

let res = list.sort((prev, next) => {
    let prevDueDate = prev.splits ? prev.splits.map(el => el.dueDate).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))[0] : prev.dueDate;
    let nextDueDate = next.splits ? next.splits.map(el => el.dueDate).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))[0] : next.dueDate;

    return prevDueDate.localeCompare(nextDueDate);
}).map(el => ({ id: el.id }));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is the solution that you are looking for.

```js
const list = [
  {
    id: 1,
    amount: 20,
    dueDate: '2021-05-01',
    splits: [
      { id: 1, amount: 15, dueDate: '2021-09-01' }, 
      { id: 2, amount: 5, dueDate: '2021-03-01' }
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    amount: 45,
    dueDate: '2021-07-01',
    splits: [
      { id: 1, amount: 20, dueDate: '2021-11-01' },
      { id: 2, amount: 24, dueDate: '2021-09-01' },
      { id: 3, amount: 1, dueDate: '2021-10-01' }
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    amount: 10,
    dueDate: '2021-08-01'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    amount: 30,
    dueDate: '2021-06-01',
    splits: [{ id: 1, amount: 30, dueDate: '2021-01-01' }]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    amount: 15,
    dueDate: '2021-04-01'
  },
];

const getDateForObj = (obj) => {
  if (obj.splits) {
    const dateList = obj.splits.map((split) => split.dueDate);
    const smallestDate = dateList.sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b))[0];
    return smallestDate;
  } else {
    return obj.dueDate
  }
}
const newList = list.sort((a, b) =>{
  const aDate = getDateForObj(a);
  const bDate = getDateForObj(b);
  return new Date(aDate) - new Date(bDate);
});
console.log(newList);
```